Problem with client cache in Angular 17.1
I have a cache problem in Angular 17.1, all my files are hashed, and yet the client browser does not receive the update. There are users with 4 days of cache and the versions I upload have no effect on some devices, around 15% of devices do not receive the corrected files,
Below are the solutions I did and didn't have any results, is there any different solution that can be done?
1 - I set Hash in Angular Json:
"outputHashing": "all",

2 - I set it to nginx.config so that it deletes and redownloads all files
  location ~* \.(js|css|html|woff|woff2|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|eot|ttf)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
            add_header Pragma "no-cache";
            expires 0;
        }

3 -  I set meta for no-cache in index.html
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate" />
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

4 - Exclude archive of servicework
5 - force cache clearing from time to time
caches.keys().then((keyList) =>
      Promise.all(
        keyList.map((key) => {
            caches.delete(key)
          
        }
                    )
          )
                  )

I made all these attempts and still I can't kill the client cache to get my most updated .ts files, help me

It's hard to tell what is the exact reason, but if users keep the browser tab opened for several days and never refresh or restart the browser, the updated files are never requested again from the server. You can fix this with service workers which periodically check for application updates and download them in the background.

Have you tried changing the name of the default files of angular so it forces a refresh?

Use the comments for questions.
